GitHub action on "ubuntu-latest" fails to run valid bash script with syntax error
I have a bash script, which I tested locally on macOS machine and Ubuntu22.04 and it worked. However, when running the same script in GitHub action ubuntu-latest - without any further special configuration, it fails.
This is my bash script:
set -e

get_named_query_output=$(aws athena get-named-query --named-query-id $NAMED_QUERY_ID)
named_query_string=$(echo "$get_named_query_output" | jq -r '.NamedQuery.QueryString')
named_query_workgroup=$(echo "$get_named_query_output" | jq -r '.NamedQuery.WorkGroup')
named_query_database=$(echo "$get_named_query_output" | jq -r '.NamedQuery.Database')

start_query_output=$(aws athena start-query-execution \
    --query-string "$named_query_string" \
    --work-group "$named_query_workgroup" \
    --query-execution-context "Database=$named_query_database" \
    --result-configuration "OutputLocation=$S3_OUTPUT_LOCATION")

query_execution_id=$(echo "$start_query_output" | jq -r '.QueryExecutionId')

check_interval_seconds=5
start_run_time=$(date +%s)

poll_execution_status() {
    while true; do
        current_run_time=$(date +%s)

        if ((current_run_time - start_run_time > 30)); then
            echo "Timeout exceeded"

            exit 1
        fi

        execution_status=$(aws athena get-query-execution \
            --query-execution-id "$query_execution_id" \
            --query 'QueryExecution.Status.State' \
            --output text)

        if [ "$execution_status" == "SUCCEEDED" ]; then
            echo "Query execution succeeded"

            exit 0
        elif [ "$execution_status" == "FAILED" ] || [ "$execution_status" == "CANCELLED" ]; then
            echo "Query execution failed or was cancelled"

            exit 1
        else
            echo "Query is still running. Checking again in $check_interval_seconds seconds..."

            sleep $check_interval_seconds
        fi
    done
}

poll_execution_status

Just a note (although I don't think it causes the issue), the script is triggered from Terraform terraform_data resource:
resource "terraform_data" "create_athena_table_usage_script" {
  provisioner "local-exec" {
    command = "chmod +x ${path.module}/scripts/generate-athena-table-usage.sh; ${path.module}/scripts/generate-athena-table-usage.sh"

    environment = {
      NAMED_QUERY_ID     = aws_athena_named_query.create_usage_table.id
      S3_OUTPUT_LOCATION = "s3://${module.s3_bucket_usage_data.s3_bucket_id}"
    }
  }
}

I get 2 strange errors in the GitHub action:
First error
module.usage_service["production"].terraform_data.create_athena_table_usage_script (local-exec): modules/usage-service/scripts/generate-athena-table-usage.sh: 34: [: SUCCEEDED: unexpected operator
module.usage_service["production"].terraform_data.create_athena_table_usage_script (local-exec): modules/usage-service/scripts/generate-athena-table-usage.sh: 38: [: SUCCEEDED: unexpected operator
module.usage_service["production"].terraform_data.create_athena_table_usage_script (local-exec): modules/usage-service/scripts/generate-athena-table-usage.sh: 38: [: SUCCEEDED: unexpected operator
module.usage_service["production"].terraform_data.create_athena_table_usage_script (local-exec): Query is still running. Checking again in 5 seconds...

Second error
 module.usage_service["production"].terraform_data.create_athena_table_usage_script (local-exec): modules/usage-service/scripts/generate-athena-table-usage.sh: 23: current_run_time: not found
module.usage_service["staging"].terraform_data.create_athena_table_usage_script (local-exec): modules/usage-service/scripts/generate-athena-table-usage.sh: 23: current_run_time: not found


Put #!/bin/bash as the first line of your script. otherwise it would use sh, not bash.

I am voting to close the question because following the bash tag's note would have solved the issue:
NOTE: Do not ask a bash question until you have copy/pasted your script into http://shellcheck.net and fixed all of the issues it tells you about. This tag is for questions about scripts written for the Bash command shell. Questions about the interactive use of Bash are more likely to be on-topic on Unix & Linux Stack Exchange or Super User than on Stack Overflow.

You need a proper shebang to tell it is Bash or POSIX sh.
Although even with Bash, your script's syntax is not ok..
Reminder of what the bash tag's description says:

NOTE: Do not ask a bash question until you have copy/pasted your script into http://shellcheck.net and fixed all of the issues it tells you about. This tag is for questions about scripts written for the Bash command shell. Questions about the interactive use of Bash are more likely to be on-topic on Unix & Linux Stack Exchange or Super User than on Stack Overflow.

Here is a breakdown of issues in your script with comments:
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# This is to be absolutely avoided in production code like a CICD script
# See: https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/105
set -e

# Missing double quote to prevent globbing and word splitting.
# See: https://www.shellcheck.net/wiki/SC2086
get_named_query_output=$(aws athena get-named-query --named-query-id $NAMED_QUERY_ID)

named_query_string=$(echo "$get_named_query_output" | jq -r '.NamedQuery.QueryString')
named_query_workgroup=$(echo "$get_named_query_output" | jq -r '.NamedQuery.WorkGroup')
named_query_database=$(echo "$get_named_query_output" | jq -r '.NamedQuery.Database')

start_query_output=$(aws athena start-query-execution \
    --query-string "$named_query_string" \
    --work-group "$named_query_workgroup" \
    --query-execution-context "Database=$named_query_database" \
    --result-configuration "OutputLocation=$S3_OUTPUT_LOCATION")

query_execution_id=$(echo "$start_query_output" | jq -r '.QueryExecutionId')

check_interval_seconds=5
start_run_time=$(date +%s)

poll_execution_status() {
    while true; do
        current_run_time=$(date +%s)

        if ((current_run_time - start_run_time > 30)); then
            echo "Timeout exceeded"

            exit 1
        fi

        execution_status=$(aws athena get-query-execution \
            --query-execution-id "$query_execution_id" \
            --query 'QueryExecution.Status.State' \
            --output text)

        # Do not mix POSIX grammar test [ with Bash == string comparison
        # Use either [[ "$var" == 'STRING' ]] or [ "$var" = 'STRING' ]
        if [ "$execution_status" == "SUCCEEDED" ]; then
            echo "Query execution succeeded"

            exit 0
        # Do not mix POSIX grammar test [ with Bash == string comparison
        # Use either [[ "$var" == 'STRING' ]] or [ "$var" = 'STRING' ]
        elif [ "$execution_status" == "FAILED" ] || [ "$execution_status" == "CANCELLED" ]; then
            echo "Query execution failed or was cancelled"

            exit 1
        else
            echo "Query is still running. Checking again in $check_interval_seconds seconds..."

            sleep $check_interval_seconds
        fi
    done
}

# This statement ca never be reached
poll_execution_status

Anyway here is a POSIX shell grammar version of your script with some fixes
#!/usr/bin/env sh

aws athena get-named-query --named-query-id "$NAMED_QUERY_ID" |
    jq -r '.NamedQuery|(.QueryString,.WorkGroup,.Database)' | {
    read -r named_query_string
    read -r named_query_workgroup
    read -r named_query_database

    start_query_output=$(aws athena start-query-execution \
        --query-string "$named_query_string" \
        --work-group "$named_query_workgroup" \
        --query-execution-context "Database=$named_query_database" \
        --result-configuration "OutputLocation=$S3_OUTPUT_LOCATION")

    query_execution_id=$(jq -nr --argjson j "$start_query_output" '$j.QueryExecutionId')

    check_interval_seconds=5
    start_run_time=$(date +%s)

    poll_execution_status() {
        while [ $(($(date +%s) - start_run_time)) -le 30 ]; do

            execution_status=$(aws athena get-query-execution \
                --query-execution-id "$query_execution_id" \
                --query 'QueryExecution.Status.State' \
                --output text)

            case "$execution_status" in
                'SUCCEEDED')
                    printf %s\\n "Query execution succeeded"
                    exit 0
                ;;
                'FAILED')
                    printf %s\\n "Query execution failed or was cancelled"
                    exit 1
                ;;
                *)
                printf 'Query is still running. Checking again in %d seconds...\n' $check_interval_seconds
                sleep $check_interval_seconds
                ;;
            esac
        done
        printf %s\\n "Timeout exceeded"
        exit 1
    }

    poll_execution_status
}

